# mongoose findByIdAndRemove() strange behavior

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im working with mongoose and when i tried using query like `.findByIdAndRemove()`
it deleted the content but not remove the product from the database
it just turn it to `Null`

like

```
{"_id":"5d67502aaffb3729a0e24904","name":null,"image":null,"price":null,"desc":null,"__v":0}
```

**Form**

```
<form action='/product/<%=product._id%>' method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>

//Route
router.post('/product/:productId',productController.deleteProduct)

//controller
//delete product
exports.deleteProduct = (req, res, next)=>{
    const prodId = req.params.productId
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(prodId)
    .then(() =>{
        console.log('has been deleted')
        res.redirect('/product')
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
}
```

Comment: `Product.findByIdAndRemove(prodId, (err, result) => { if(err) console.log(err); else console.log(result) })` try callback function. u find out error. Please share the model or schema

Comment: it's give me the same behavior without any errors in the console

//schmea
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    image : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    price : {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    desc : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema)

Comment: try `Product.remove({_id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(prodId)}, (err, result) => { if(err) console.log(err); else console.log(result) })` try this code

Comment: or try this `Product.remove({name: 'yourName'}, (err, result) => { if(err) console.log(err); else console.log(result) })`

Answer (score 0):

Could please try below delete script.

It's removing by one document using id

```
Product.remove({_id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(prodId)}, (err, result) => { 
 if(err) console.log(err); 
 else console.log(result) 
})
```

It's removing document by _id

```
 Product.findByIdAndRemove(prodId, (err, result) => { 
     if(err) console.log(err); 
     else console.log(result) 
    })
```

It's removing by one document

```
Product.remove({name: 'yourName'}, (err, result) => { 
 if(err) console.log(err); 
 else console.log(result) 
})
```

or another option

```
Product.deleteOne({ name: 'Eddard Stark' }, callback);
```

In router

```
router.delete('/product/:productId',productController.deleteProduct)
```

In the front end, you call delete API. If the interest you can learn MEARN Stack CRUD operation in [GitHub link](https://github.com/senthilmca90/mern-crud)

Comment: thanks man for trying helping me....

the problem is with the route when i add /delete at the end it worked now

/product/:productId/delete

while i tried to use ?_method=DELETE in the form 
and
router.delete()

it didn't work i don't know why

Comment: try console.log(req.params.productId) first. use router.delete('/product/:productId',productController.deleteProduct) and delete api in frontend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
Product.findByIdAndRemove(prodId)
.then(function () {
    console.log("Successfully removed");
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
res.redirect("/");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in an ID to `findByIdAndRemove` and it removes it. However, just like  `findById`, it also returns the doc. So, you do not need to call both of them.

When removing using `Todo.findByIdAndRemove` method, this is going to let us remove a Todo by id, and we can provide a callback. The callback is going to get the doc back. You could call it `doc`, or `todo` since it is a Todo item